# django distinct in the ListViews

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, distinct-values

I am having an issue with a distinct in the ListViews
I have a connection M2M between “Allergeni” and “Ingredient” and another one M2M between “Product” and “Ingredient” that goes through the table “Materiali”.

I need to obtain a table with the whole list of “Product” with an extra field “Allergeni” that contains only a unique version for of all the values in the raw

model for ingredients:

```
class Ingredient (models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey("Categoria")
    costokg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'))
    resa = models.IntegerField()
    prezzopulito = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3,default=Decimal('0.00'))
    componenti = models.TextField()
    allergeni = models.ManyToManyField("Allergeni", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ingredients:detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})



class Allergeni (models.Model):
    allergene = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

model for products:

```
class Product (models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    descrizione = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    prezzo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'))
    peso_finale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'))
    categoria = models.ForeignKey("Categoria")
    tag = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", blank=True)
    componenti = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='Materiali', through_fields=('object_id', 'ingrediente'))
    creazione = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    aggiornamento = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

class Materiali (models.Model):
    object_id = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingrediente = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="materia_prima")
    peso = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'))


    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingrediente.nome
```

product view

```
def product_list(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all() \
        .annotate(total=Round((Sum((F('materiali__ingrediente__prezzopulito')/1000) * F('materiali__peso'))) / (F('peso_finale'))) * 1000 )


    materiali = Materiali.objects.all()

    allergeni= materiali.values_list('ingrediente__allergeni__allergene', flat=True).distinct()

    context = {
        "object_list" : queryset,
        "title": "List",
        "allergeni": allergeni,
    }

    return render(request, "product/product_list.html", context)
```

Code https://pastebin.com/LcyPF8v8

With “values_list” I obtain unique values but not filtered by the object in the forloop, and I can't use TemplateTag, so I prefer other options if it's possible.

How can I do that?

Best,

Comment: distinct() method can work properly if you're using Postgresql Database because Django provide distinct method with many options.

Comment: I have try with Postgresql, but I have the same problem, distinct works, but it does not filter on the product's queryset during the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your models :

```
class Ingredient (models.Model):
    ...
    allergeni = models.ManyToManyField("Allergeni", blank=True, 
                                       related_name="ingredienti")
    ...

class Product (models.Model):
    ...
    componenti = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, 
                                        through='Materiali', through_fields=('product', 'ingrediente'), 
                                        related_name="prodotti")
    ...

class Materiali(models.Model):
    ...
    # Don't use object_id this is an object
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # use plural for 1..* related_name
    ingrediente = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, 
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                    related_name="materie_prime") 

    ...
```

So in your view:

```
def product_list(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all().annotate(total=Round((Sum((F('materiali__ingrediente__prezzopulito')/1000) * F('materiali__peso'))) / (F('peso_finale'))) * 1000 )
    product_info = {}
    for product in queryset:
        product_allergeni = Allergeni.objects.filter(ingredienti__prodotti=product).values_list('allergene', flat=True)
        product_info.update({product.id:list(product_allergeni)})

    context = {
        "object_list" : queryset,
        "title": "List",
        "product_info": product_info,
    }

    return render(request, "product/product_list.html", context)
```

In your template, instead:

```
<ul>
{% for product in object_list %}
<li>
  <p>Product : {{product.name}}</p>
  <ol>Allergeni :
  {% for product_id,allergeni in product_info.items %}
      {% if product_id == product.id %}
          {% for allergene in allergeni %}
            <li>{{ allergene }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  </ol>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

N.B.

1. To access directly to your product_info dict you can use [this trick](https://push.cx/2007/django-template-tag-for-dictionary-access) :  instead of cycling every key,value
2. Use always english variables to allow not italian proggammers to better help and understand you  ;)

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Will this not work?

```
allergeni= materiali.distinct('ingrediente__allergeni__allergene').values_list('ingrediente__allergeni__allergene', flat=True)
```

Comment: thanks, but I use mysql so I con't use .distinct like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use **set** of **python** that can automatic distinct array type object So no need to use distinct() for array type of object.

```
allergeni = set(materiali.values_list('ingrediente__allergeni__allergene', flat=True))
```

Foo filter product queryset based on Allergeni, you can use below

```
queryset = Product.objects.all() \
        .annotate(total=Round((Sum((F('materiali__ingrediente__prezzopulito')/1000) * F('materiali__peso'))) / (F('peso_finale'))) * 1000 )

materiali = Materiali.objects.all()
allergeni= materiali.values_list('ingrediente__allergeni__allergene', flat=True).distinct()
queryset = queryset.filter(materiali__ingrediente__allergeni__in=allergeni)
```

Now you will get distinct product that has ***allergeni***

Comment: thanks, I had already tried that solution too.
For the distinct it works, but it does not filter on the product's queryset during the loop